# Conway's game of life code, error saying there is an else without an if

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, conways-game-of-life

Unsure about why there is an error saying that there is an else without an if for the code for Conway's game of life. Also any guidance for what to do next would be appreciated. I have done up to that part where it will read the array and then scan a document but unsure whether I have done it right of not so any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

class LifeGrid
{
 private int[][] a;  
 private int currentGenerator;

 public LifeGrid(int x, int y, String filename ) throws FileNotFoundException
 {
   a = new int[x][y];  //initialising array with x and y
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("seed.txt")); 

  while(scanner.hasNextLine())  
  {
   String b = scanner.nextLine();
   for(int i = 0; i<x; i++)    //first is for line block
   {
    System.out.println(i);
    for(int j = 0; j<y; j++)  //second for individual blocks 
    {
     if(b.charAt(j)=='*')  
    {
     a[i][j]= b.charAt(j);  
    }
   }
  }
 }
}

public void show()
{
 for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++)
 {
  for(int j = 0; j<a[i].length; j++)
  {
   if(a[i][j]==b.charAt(j));
   {
     System.out.println('*');
   }
   else
   {
     System.out.println(' ');
   }
  }
   System.out.println();
 }
  System.out.println("Current Generation: " + currentGenerator);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(a[i][j]==b.charAt(j));
```

to

```
if(a[i][j]==b.charAt(j))
```

`;` closes the `if` statement, thus causing the following `else` to have no corresponding `if`.

Comment: Now when I have done that I am getting an error saying error: cannot find symbol
     if(a[i][j] == b.charAt(j))

Comment: error: cannot find symbol
     if(a[i][j] == b.charAt(j))

Comment: @MunafPatel Your `show` method doesn't have a `b` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You put a semicolon after an `if`. There is no need to do that. Moreover you shouldn't do this because this is a statement. After statments there's no need to put semicolons. After method definitions you also don't put semicolons (eventually in interfaces but I don't mean these).

Change `if(a[i][j]==b.charAt(j));`
to `if(a[i][j]==b.charAt(j))`

Comment: I am getting this error nowerror: cannot find symbol
     if(a[i][j] == b.charAt(j))

Comment: There's no `b` variable.